# Дано натуральное число n. Как сделать рекурсивную функцию, которая возвращает строку чисел от 1 до n, разделенных пробелами?

Tags: javascript

Дано натуральное число n. Надо написать рекурсивную функцию, которая возвращает строку чисел от 1 до n, разделенных пробелом. Основная сложность задачи заключается в том, что ее необходимо решить с использованием рекурсии. Я пробовал:

```
function my_function(n) {
    if (n <= 1) return 1;
    return n * my_function(n - 1);
  }
  console.log(my_function(9));
```

Но у меня выводит не то, что нужно. Подскажите, как это сделать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
function my_function(n) {
  return n <= 1? 1 : my_function(n - 1) + ' ' + n;
}
console.log(my_function(11));
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
    function my_function(n) {
        if (n <= 1) return 1;
        return my_function(n-1) + " " + n;
    }
    console.log(my_function(11))
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: Зачем почти дословно повторять имеющийся ответ??